# OpenShift / NGiNX reverse proxy guidance - pass to SDN-based addresses?

Tags: nginx, openshift, uwsgi

I am configuring a fairly complicated app for a client, and am getting stuck with the reverse proxy model. As far as my understanding goes, we should proxy_pass/uwsgi_pass to the internal endpoint addresses (172.30.0.0/16), such as

appname.project.svc.cluster.local

However, these addresses, although DNS-resolvable from within the pods which make up the app, are not reachable.  The pods seem to run from the 10.200.0.0/14 SDN address range, and so no route exists for them by default from within the pod.

The alternative might be to proxy_pass to the exposed routes of each service, but this seems wrong - the request would then be routed back out of the OpenShift pod space, back through the (default haproxy) router to the exposed endpoint address.

What is the correct way?

Seasons greetings and thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer my own question, I wanted to mention.. I just discovered the other types of SkyDNS-based ranges, such as:

app.project.endpoints.cluster.local

See here: [Table 1. DNS Example Names](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/networking/networking.html)

These are reachable from the pods.

Thanks for your time